# OpenGL: Why isn't discarding fragments the same as setting their alpha to zero?

Tags: java, opengl-es, bezier

I've been drawing Bezier curves in OpenGL ES 2, referencing the following [HLSL](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html) shader. Below shows the result:

[image: Bezier Curve 1]

The shader referenced relies on if statements to accomplish the effect:

```
        float alpha  = (0.5f - sd);
        if(alpha > 1f) {
             alpha = 1f; 
        }
        else if(alpha < 0f) {
             discard; 
        }
        else {
             alpha = alpha; 
        }
        gl_FragColor = vec4(uColor.x, uColor.y, uColor.z, alpha);
```

As these greatly degrade performance in the OpenGL pipeline, I thought that instead of using an if statement to coerce the alpha or discard the fragment, I could just force the edge pixels to become transparent if they were less than 0f, using the clamp function:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(uColor.x, uColor.y, uColor.z, clamp(alpha, 0f, 1f));
```

However, this does not work as the side pixels remain partially visible:

[image]

My question is, am I missing something fundamental about the `discard` function? Why should zero alpha quantities be visible at all?

Comment: Well, without a blending function that does something based on source alpha or an alpha test after the fragment shader runs (this is no longer supported in modern GL), setting alpha to **0** is not going to do much of anything. In addition to that, `discard` kills every thing that would have been output including depth and stencil.

Comment: Hi @AndonM.Coleman, I am rendering within an OpenGL context where alpha quantities can be properly represented, for example I can fade a triangle or an image. Do you think these artifacts may come from those other buffers?

Comment: Wait, you were correct! Blend had been deactivated for this render region. Please submit your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The alpha component has no intrinsic meaning in OpenGL.

People often assume that it automatically means transparency, but that is really just a consequence of the way blending and `glAlphaFunc (...)` (used to) work.

#### Typically when you want the alpha component to do something you use alpha blending:

```
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

^^^ Color = FragmentColor * FragmentAlpha  +  FramebufferColor * (1.0 - FragmentAlpha)
```

#### Or an alpha test:

```
glAlphaFunc (GL_GREATER, 0.0f);
```

The latter is not supported in modern OpenGL because this test can be implemented in a fragment shader using, you guessed it, `discard`.

In either case, you have to enable `GL_BLEND` or `GL_ALPHA_TEST` respectively for them to do anything.

---

As for the differences between `discard` and using a **0.0** alpha value ***with*** alpha blending, `discard` will actually discard depth and stencil values in addition to eliminating the source color. `GL_ALPHA_TEST` serves a similar role in places where it is supported (it is/was a per-fragment test that occurs after the fragment shader runs and discards fragments that fail the test).

Comment: Very informative answer. Thanks for all of your help!